# Not able to start python 2.7 notebook (yet 2.7 environment is created)

Tags: windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

After struggling a bit with Conda and Windows' PATH variables I got to create and activate a Python 2.7 environment in addition to the Python 3 that already had.

After activating the environment, the command

```
(py27) C:\Anaconda3>conda list
```

states that, indeed, Python 2.7.13 is installed on that environment:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xythP.png)

But when I try to create a Jupyter Notebook with Python 2.7, I can't see that option, only Python 3, as before.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Thanks to Michael Galarnyk's [GREAT video on this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFCBiP9Gkoo).

[Here](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097)'s a link to the corresponding post in his blog.